# jwt.sign() i get error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line depending on the options

Tags: node.js, jwt

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");  

jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    algorithm: "RS256",
    expiresIn: "14 days",
  });
```

leads to
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)

```
jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    //algorithm: "RS256",
    expiresIn: "14 days",
  });
```

works perfectly fine

the setup:
Operating System: Mac OS
Node v17.0.1

```
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-server": "^3.4.0",
  "apollo-server-core": "^3.4.0",
  "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
  "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
  "google-auth-library": "^7.10.1",
  "graphql": "^15.6.1",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
  "pg": "^8.7.1",
  "sequelize": "^6.7.0"
},
```

Comment: os? package.json? nide version?

Comment: mac os,"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^3.4.0",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "google-auth-library": "^7.10.1",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.7.0"
  },

node v17.0.1

Answer (score 4):

`RS256` stands for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256, that means it uses a digital signature generated using a private RSA key. Your `process.env.JWT_SECRET` is either a string or a buffer that is not a private RSA key in PEM format, ergo Node's crypto module fails to parse it as such. That's the error you're seeing.

When you remove the `algorithm` option the library automatically chooses an algorithm based on your "secret" input, in this case - a symmetric secret, `HS256` will be used instead (and is the [documented default](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback)).

Answer (score 3):

This error says that there is an error with the format of the keys you provided. The PEM format needs the lines

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

in a line of their own surrounding your key. Adapt for private keys.

If I have to take a guess, you most likely forgot this.